# Analysis+Linear Algebra problem.

Tags: linear-algebra

**Problem**:

Let $V$ be the space of convergent sequences of real numbers. Let $W$ be the
subset of $V$ consisting of sequences converging to $0$ and let $Z$ be the subset of $V$ consisting of constant sequences. Prove or disprove that $W, Z$ are subspaces of $V$ and $W\oplus Z=V.$

I have shown that $W$ and $Z$ are subspace of $V.$ And I think that it must be the case that $V=W\oplus Z.$ This is because $\{v_n\}\in V$ can be written as $v_n=(v_n-v)+v$, where $(v_n)\to v.$ the first part converges to $0$ and the second part forms a constant sequence $\{v\}.$ We also have that $W\cap Z=\{0_n\}$ and thus $V=W\oplus Z.$ However, I have a feeling that there is something that I am missing and so please let me know where I am making an error.

Comment: Your solution is fine. If this is an exercise, you can do your steps more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

To prove $V=W\oplus Z$ we have to prove two things:

First we have to prove $W\cap Z=0$. This is clear, the only constant sequence converging to $0$ is $0$.

Secondly we have to prove that if $a$ is a converging sequence then $a=b+c$ where $b$ is a constant sequence and $c$ is a sequence  converging to $0$.

To do this suppose $a$ converges to $l$. Let $b$ be the constant $l$ sequence and let $c=a-l$. We have to prove that $c$ converges to $0$, but in general we have that if $z_1$ and $z_2$ are tow converging sequences then $z_1-z_2$ converges to the difference of their convergence points.

Comment: Then I am guessing that my solution is correct, right?

Comment: it looks good, just make sure you already proved they are both subspaces

Comment: Cool! Thanks for your reply.